# Warning: Data in the database will be overwritten and will not be recoverable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I want to unload my application on ROR on Heroku. I unload my application on Heroku, but I have no database. What I should do that my database unloaded on Heroku. I received many errors. One of this error is introduced brlow. Now my website is work, but I don't have database on it. I read Heroku Dev... I am sorry, but I can't unload database. What the error? Can you help me? Please, say me commands, which I should complete, that my database is work on Heroku.

My website: http://priroda-site.tk/

**My error:**

```
    ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/appq$ heroku db:pull
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: postgres://postgres:ippolit@localhost/Mirp?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'postgres://postgres:ippolit@localhost/Mirp?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: mighty-oasis-6099
 !    To proceed, type "mighty-oasis-6099" or re-run this command with --confirm mighty-oasis-6099
```

**database.yml**

```
    development:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: Mirp
      host: localhost
      username: postgres
      password: ippolit
      encoding: utf8


    # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
    # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
    # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
    test:
      adapter: sqlite3
      database: db/test.sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production_db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `heroku pg:pull` instead of `heroku db:pull` which has been deprecated.

The error you're receiving when downloading (pulling) your database is because you already have an existing database with that name in your local postgres instance. You can either overwrite the contents of that database by typing `mighty-oasis-6099`or pull the contents into a new database in your local dev:

`heroku pg:pull Mirp_new --app mighty-oasis-6099`

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull for further options